# What is pulling up tufts of grass all over my lawn?

Tags: lawn, grass, pest-damage

I went to mow the yard today and found 1-2 inch plugs of grass pulled out of the ground all over the place. It looks more like the result of digging than a deliberate pulling out.

What could be doing this, and what can I do about it?

Comment: I have a similar problem with my lawn - the culprits are squirrels digging up the nuts and seeds that settle in the thatch when they are blown down from surrounding trees. Do you have any trees nearby?

Comment: @Mancuniensis I practically live under a forest :)

Comment: This time of year, at least up north, squirrels are more likely to be burying than digging up - but the effect will be the same.  If it's near oak tree(s) or other nut trees, that's probably it.

Comment: i have the same thing in my garden, I picked one up cause it looked like a face on it and as I was checking it out, I noticed it looked like it had a mesh covering on it, more like a burlap bag was the texture and feel I should say. I grow my garden in this soil, but this is the first year I seen this and believe it or not my garden grew fast, but it didn't have a good taste to it...corn, tomatoes, lettuce none of it tasted good. The soil didn't look right looked like little people of some kind of unnatural decent and when I took to tearing up some of the clumps, they would fall out in little

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had this happen many times over the years.  In my case, it was flocks of crows tearing up the lawn looking for grubs.  It's almost comical how they rip out a piece of sod and toss it over their shoulder.

Almost.

On the other hand, the grubs can't be good either.  You might want to try some grub killer.

Comment: I've seen this kind of damage from robins (at least I think it was robins, I didn't catch them in the act).

Comment: Skunks will do it here (New Hampshire).  Armadillos will do it down your way, too.. anything that likes those tasty grubs.